# Building .netstandard library on linux using command line options

Tags: .net, .net-standard

How to build a project targeted to netstandard on linux using command line options. Can MSBUILD/csc be used to build the files on linux.

I had googled and found that .NET Core sdk provides "dotnet" tool to compile the code.

But to compile a code which has to be targeted to "netstandard" what command line tool has to be used which comes along the sdk.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The information on the target framework can simply be indicated in the `.csproj` file.

Then you execute `dotnet publish` or `dotnet build` to generate binaries.

For instance, here is a `MyProject.csproj` example of a project that has several target framework for .NET standard :

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFrameworks>netstandard2.0;netstandard1.6;netstandard1.4</TargetFrameworks>
    <RootNamespace>MyName.MyProject</RootNamespace>
    <AssemblyName>MyName.MyProject</AssemblyName>
    <TreatWarningsAsErrors>true</TreatWarningsAsErrors>

    <Configurations>Debug;Release</Configurations>
    <LangVersion>7.3</LangVersion>
  </PropertyGroup>
  ....
</Project>
```

If I want the .NET standard 2.0 output I can execute :

`dotnet publish MyProject.csproj --framework netstandard2.0` (with maybe other unrelated options)

Note: usually, you need only one target framework.

Comment: BTW, unless the code base requires conditional compilation, it is less likely to need many .NET Standard versions in `TargetFrameworks`.

Comment: yes, you are right. In one particular project example I actually needed to have several target, but usually there is only one needed as you said.